# Nuxt now deploy failing: error nuxt@1.0.0: "node" is incompatible

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, yarnpkg, vercel

I am trying to deploy a nuxt application to now platform, but it is failing due to node version.

Here is the error message:

> `error nuxt@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "10.x". Got "8.10.0"`

my now.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder",
      "config": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

and package.json has

```
"engines": {
   "node": "10.x"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Issue on zeit community https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/nuxt-now-deploy-failing-error-nuxt-1-0-0-node-is-incompatible~781bafcb-1f88-4c79-8fb5-0f028b8a75c8